# one of those human hors d'oeuvres

Tags: word-usage

> The Duke of Falvertoon was one of **those** human hors d'oeuvres that
>   stimulate the public appetite for sensation without giving it much to
>   feed on. As a mere child he had been precociously brilliant; he had
>   declined the editorship of the Anglian Review at an age when most boys
>   are content to have declined mensa, a table, and though he could not
>   claim to have originated the Futurist movement in literature, his
>   "Letters to a possible Grandson," written at the age of fourteen, had
>   attracted considerable notice. In later days his brilliancy had been
>   less conspicuously displayed.
>
> from [The Unkindest Blow](http://www.eastoftheweb.com/short-stories/UBooks/UnkiBlow802.shtml), a short story by Saki

What is the role of "those"?

What is the differende between "one of those human hors d'oeuvres" and "one of human hors d'oeuvres"?

Answer (score 1):

"One of those" adds significance to the phrase "human hors d'oevres" and changes its meaning from a unique metaphor for the Duke to indicating there is a subset of such people that everyone has some experience with or knowledge of.

It's a way of telling the reader "You know the kind of person I'm taking about."

The alternative, by the way, would be to say

> The Duke was **a** human hors d'oeuvre.